# Confusing error when deleting dynamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to implement a simple merge sort algorithm. What I am very confusing is that
I keep getting the following error message right after the "array2" is deleted.

"
 free(): invalid next size (fast)
"

Please advise. Thank you very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

void merge_sort(int*,int,int);

int main(){
  //cout << "Max int: " << INT_MAX <<endl;
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int* array = new int(n+1);
  for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
  merge_sort(array,1,n);
  cout << "--------------------------------------------" <<endl;
  for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    cout << array[i] <<endl;
}

void merge_sort(int* array,int p,int r){
  cout << p << ' ' << r <<endl;
  if (p == r)
    return;
  int q = int((p+r)/2);
  merge_sort(array,p,q);
  merge_sort(array,q+1,r);
  //(p..q)  and (q+1 .. r) sorted, then merge this two sorted array
  int n1 = q-p+1;
  int n2 = r-q;
  cout << "Mark1 " <<n1<<' '<<n2<<endl;
  int *array1;
  array1 = new int(n1+1);
  int *array2;
  array2 = new int(n2+1);
  for (int i=p; i<=q; i++)
    array1[i-p] = array[i];
  for (int i=q+1; i<=r; i++)
    array2[i-q-1] = array[i];
  array1[n1] = INT_MAX;
  array2[n2] = INT_MAX;  //CONSTANT, serve as sentinel

  int p1 = 0;
  int p2 = 0;
  cout << "Mark2" << endl;
  for (int i=p; i<=r; i++){
    if (array1[p1]<array2[p2]){
      array[i] = array1[p1];
      p1++;
    }else{
      array[i] = array2[p2];
      p2++;`enter code here`
    }
  }   
  cout << "Mark3" << endl;
  delete [] array2;
  cout << "Delete array2 " << endl;

  delete [] array1;
  cout << "Delete array1 " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Declaring a pointer without assigning it to anything is UB, or Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Rapptz  no, accessing a pointer without having previously assigned to it or initialised it is UB.

Comment: @SethCarnegie thanks, I knew something about pointers without assigning anything to it was UB but I wasn't sure what.

Comment: @Rapptz yeah, it's the same for any variable.

Comment: The immediate giveway is that you have calls to `delete[]` but not to `new[]`.

Comment: guys, please see my comments below on one of the answers.  The only issue is because () is used when [] should be used, so the amount of memory allocated is not enough causing the code to write over unallocated memory, which, in turn, trashes markers that the allocator put in.  There is no University of Buffalo issue from not initializing array[0] or pointer declaration etc.  It's not very smart to just waste 1 byte, but that is NOT the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
new int(n+1)
```

Creates a single `int` on the free-store and initialises it with `n+1`, and right away you access it out of bounds with `array[1]`. You want brackets:

```
new int[n + 1]
```

Which will create an array. The same goes for every other place like that in the program.

Also, since you are starting your loop at `1`, the object `array[0]` is uninitialised and you get undefined behaviour if you access it, which you do. This is wasting an array element for nothing and setting up traps for yourself, I recommend you don't add 1 to the array size and start your indices from 0.

Comment: almost there... but not quite.  the issue is not from uninitialized array[0].  try again.

Comment: @thang the issue is the first thing I mentioned.

Comment: but why does he get that error...you're so close.  i'll get rid of the -1 when you get it.

Comment: so the issue actually is because he (assuming male) writes to memory that he hasn't allocated by running past the end of the array.  this tramps over the heap's marker, and that's where the error comes from when he tries to free.

Comment: @thang Yes, I thought that was clearly implied by telling him to fix the array allocation. But even fixing that still leaves the program with UB.

Comment: actually the uninitialized array[0] doesn't cause any problem.  he never uses that first element.  i don't know why everyone brings that up.  it's 1 wasted slot, but it doesn't cause any problem.  it doesn't even cause University of Buffalo :p  go through the code again for yourself and see.

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you for all your suggestions. The problem is that I should use "int[n2+1]" instead of "int(n2+1)" in initialization.